# Keep Remote Desktop Display active when disconnect

Tags: remote-desktop, gui, windows-server-2016

Im trying to fix the problem with a missing GUI when i log off rdc. Im running a program that takes a partial screenshot but it is only working if i dont minimize or close the connection. It shows me the error: ".Net Framework... Unknown Exception..."

This forces me to have my computer always on too. Im looking for a solution to keep the Desktop active and also the Screen Resolution.

I tried allrady a few things like: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/arnona/2016/01/03/keeping-an-active-desktop-session/

and I also tried to disconnect with `%windir%\System32\tscon.exe RDP-Tcp#NNN /dest:console` Im not sure if this kind of disconnect worked for me, but the main problem here is obviously the changing screen resolution because all the dinows are on different places after relogging. I need the windows to hold the exact coordinates. I cant find any way to keep a static resolution.

Is there any software which can help me with my problem?

Comment: Try creating your initial session using the solution found [here](https://superuser.com/q/1288469/213131). You should then be able to connect to and later disconnect from the session without having the problem.

Comment: Thanks you, but its mentioned to make sure that the software is running when the user automatically logs in. I cant put my software in autostart since several settings have to be made by a user before disconnecting

Comment: I know that. That's why I said you should be able to connect to the session after it's created. You could manually start your program then. You should try and see if it works.

Comment: Sure, I will test it! I hope the screen resolution will stay the same or is there any way to make it "static"?

Comment: The resolution will be that configured for the physical display connected to the server.

Comment: Unfortunately its not working so far. Still the same issue. He mentioned to "populate" the Registry values. How to do this?

Comment: [How to modify the Registry](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/136393/how-to-modify-the-windows-registry)

Comment: I tried everything now. I figured out that leaving the Session with tscon.exe like mentioned above, keeps the program running without errors but the screenshots are black.

Comment: It seems that your screen shot application isn't compatible with a remote desktop session when used this way. :(

Comment: Im using C# and CopyFromScreen with specific coordinates if this helps. The only alternative to get this running is to set up a server at home with a monitor running 24/7 :( `CopyFromScreen(rect.Left, rect.Top, 0, 0, bmp.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);`